# Кнопка с основным текстом и небольшим описанием ниже

Tags: android

Как можно реализовать кнопку где например был бы основной текст по левому краю крупно жирным шрифтом, и небольшое описание в одно предложение ниже основной надписи по правому краю мелкими буквами полупрозрачное?

Comment: А как вам  надо? Динамично? Статично? Много разных способов, предназначенных для разных целей! Пожалуйста, уточните.

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете сделать `LinerLayout` добавить в него два `TextView` и оформить их как угодно. А дальше просто повесить слушатель при нажатие на него выполнять что вам нужно.

xml:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/customButtonLayout"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    <TextView android:text="First" android:id="@+id/firstTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000"></TextView>
    <TextView android:textColor="#000" android:text="Second"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/secondTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

code:

```
Typeface font=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"ARIALN.TTF") ;   
Typeface font2=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "COMPCTAN.TTF");

TextView firstTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.firstTextView);
TextView secondTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.secondTextView);

firstTextView.setTypeface(font);
secondTextView.setTypeface(font2);

LinearLayout btnLayout=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.customButtonLayout);
btnLayout.setOnClickListener(this);
```